# iOS sending parameter to selector using NSTimers

Tags: ios, parameters, selector, nstimer

Is there a way to send a parameter to the selector via a NSTimer ?

```
myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(removeTheNote:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

      - (void)removeTheNote:(NSString*)note
    {
        NSLog(@"Note %@ ----------- REMOVED!",note);
    }
```

I know that using :

```
myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(removeTheNote:myNote) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

doesn't work, so I am asking, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `userInfo` parameter for that:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(removeTheNote:) userInfo:myNote repeats:NO];
```

But you will have to modify `removeTheNote` as follows:

```
- (void)removeTheNote:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSString *note = timer.userInfo;
    NSLog(@"%@", note);
}
```

Comment: your answer is right but why do you have to use a nstimer parameter for selector?