# Passing parameters of method called by NSTimer

Tags: ios

I have a method

```
 -(void)addFunction:(int)x andY:(int)y{
    countdown--;
     if(countdown == 0){
      NSLog(@"Your time expired");
      [myTimer invalidate];
        }
  else {
    int c = 0;
      c = x+y;
    NSLog(@"%i",c);
   }

   }

 -(void)RunTimer{
   countdown = 5; //countdown has been declared as a static variable so the whole class can access it in its current state.
   NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(addFunction: :) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
```

Now my question is that, addFunction wont operate until i provide with the parameters, or else it will print Null value, How can i call a method by NSTimer that has parameters and sent those parameters too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS sending parameter to selector using NSTimers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086185/ios-sending-parameter-to-selector-using-nstimers)

Comment: why did you not use the `userInfo`, for instance? that is exactly for that purpose...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I like the solutions provided in the other answers; that of passing the variables in the `userInfo` dictionary.  However the OP is missing a fundamental concept in that he does not understand the scope of variables, which is revealed in the comment on this line:

```
countdown = 5; //countdown has been declared as a static variable so the whole class can access it in its current state.
```

Understanding the scope of a variable must be understood before you can program effectively, regardless of the language used, and so this question is more about variable scope than `NSTimer` and its invocation method.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can only pass one parameter to the method invoked by `NSTimer` and that is the instance of the timer itself.

Therefore you need to think about where those variables should *live* and it seems that making them instance variables is probably best, perhaps using a class extension.  You can also store the `NSTimer` and `countdown` variables there too:

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    int _x;
    int _y;
    NSTimer *_timer;
    int _countdown;
}

...

-(void)addFunction:(NSTimer *)timer
    _countdown--;
     if(_countdown == 0){
      NSLog(@"Your time expired");
      [_timer invalidate];
        }
  else {
    int c = 0;
      c = _x + _y;
    NSLog(@"%i",c);
   }

   }

 -(void)RunTimer{
   _countdown = 5;
   _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(addFunction:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
 }
```

Using global variables is wrong as it restricts the number of instances of the class to one; don't do it.

Comment: i just used countdown as a global variable as it needs to access the current value of countdown. 
And here how and where is x and y passed when being called by the timer?

Comment: @LightYagami You don't know what an instance variable is, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code, you need to change the method signature of `addFunction` and pass data that you want in `userInfo`

```
-(void)addFunction:(NSTimer *)timer{

    NSDictionary *data = [timer userInfo]; 
    NSInteger x = [data[@"x"] integerValue];
    NSInteger y = [data[@"y"] integerValue];

    countdown--;
    if(countdown == 0){
        NSLog(@"Your time expired");
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
    else {
        int c = 0;
        c = x+y;
        NSLog(@"%i",c);
    }

}

-(void)RunTimer{
    countdown = 5; //countdown has been declared as a static variable so the whole class can access it in its current state.

    NSDictionary *data = @{@"x" : @(5), @"y" : @(6)};

    NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(addFunction:) userInfo:data repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do like this simply

```
-(void)addFunction:(int)x andY:(int)y
{
    countdown--;
    if(countdown == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Your time expired");
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
    else {
        int c = 0;
        c = x+y;
        NSLog(@"%i",c);
    }

}

-(void)RunTimer
{
    countdown = 5; 
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(callAddFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)callAddFunction
{
    [self addFunction:10 andY:20];
}
```